# Talents that require Karma vs Discipline talents

Tags: earthdawn-1e

My question is twofold.

Have i understood clearly that you may use karma in any discipline talent?

And that you also may choose not to use karma for discipline talents that requires karma?

Using First Edition, however i use material from 3rd and classic also, as references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If the Talent has *Required* and is *Discipline Talent* you are **not required to use** *Karma* on it but you may. In First Edition this is on page 95 and is the last paragraph of the *Required Karma* section.

Comment: I find this answer to be worth much more than a downgrade.
You should add classic for completion's sake. :P